# BrowserSync not injecting styles correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have a gulp task that I wrote that used to work perfectly. One day I came in and it stopped working, even though I did not change the gulpfile.

I have a BrowserSync task that injects styles into the browser, a sass task that compiles all the sass files, and a watch task that runs the sass task whenever any sass files are modified.

The problem that is now occurring is that when I save any of my sass files, they are compiled and injected into the browser, but it seems that something is causing problems with the timing of the injection because the page will either load completely unstyled, half-styled with not all of the CSS completely loaded, or completely normal with everything working, all at random intervals. I can save 10 times in 5 seconds and get the same result every time or completely different results at random, which is what leads me to believe that something is wrong with the timing of the injection.

If I inspect the page, I can see the link to the CSS file in the head, and I can open that link in a new tab and see the complete CSS file in its entirety without any problems with that CSS file or its content.

BrowserSync task:

```
gulp.task('sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        open: true,
        proxy: {
            target: 'pariveda.local/'
        }
    });
});
```

Sass task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./assets/sass/main.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) // .on('error', sass.logError) prevents gulp from crashing when saving a typo or syntax error
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/sass'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(localSettings.publishFolder + '/assets/sass/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()); // causes injection of styles on save
});
```

Watch task:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./static/src/**/*.html', '!partials', '!components'], ['compileHTML']);
    gulp.watch('./assets/js/**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch(['./assets/vendors/js/*.js', '!./assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js'], ['vendors']);
    gulp.watch('./Views/Renderings/**/*.cshtml', ['publishCshtml']);
});
```

Default task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['sync', 'publishCshtml', 'vendors', 'javascript', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

And here is the output from my default task:

```
$ gulp
[17:39:44] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Sites\PVD\Pariveda.Web\gulpfile.js
[17:39:45] Starting 'sync'...
[17:39:45] Finished 'sync' after 17 ms
[17:39:45] Starting 'publishCshtml'...
[17:39:45] Starting 'vendors'...
[17:39:45] Starting 'javascript'...
[17:39:45] Starting 'sass'...
[17:39:45] Starting 'watch'...
[17:39:45] Finished 'watch' after 78 ms
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (main.css)
[17:39:49] Finished 'sass' after 4.87 s
[17:39:49] Finished 'vendors' after 4.89 s
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://pariveda.local
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ---------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.14.137:3000
 ---------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.14.137:3001
 ---------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (bundle.js)
[17:39:51] Finished 'javascript' after 6.49 s
```

Is something wrong with my tasks that is forcing the page to reload before the sass task has been successfully run?